# How to use oembed tags to implement rich pins

Tags: json, pinterest, oembed

I need to implement rich pins provided by pinterest (http://developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins/). One of the recommended ways is to use oembed. Unfortunately I am not familiar with oembed tags and was wondering if somebody can provide more insight. What is the syntax for oembed tags? Should I surround with  tags? Any particular place where it should be called?

Any help will be appreciated.
TIA

Comment: I'm in the same boat. The docs by Pinterest are absolutely useless, as are all the blog posts the eulogise this feature but just copy-paste all the advertising copy without actually giving any tips on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://blog.tailwindapp.com/make-rich-pins/) gives examples, but given the SEO benefits of using structured data, it might be more beneficial to use that instead for pinterest. Meta tags can also be used

From the link above:

> An oEmbed formula will look like this:

```
{
“provider_name”: “PinLeague”,
“url”: “http://pinleague.com/pricing-plans”,
“title”: “Pin League Professional Analytics Suite”,
“description”: “Gain insights and take strategic action on Pinterest with PinLeague’s Professional Analytics Suite.”,
“product_id”: “PL12345″,
“price”: 99.00,
“currency_code”: “USD”,
“brand”: “PinLeague Analytics”
“availability”: “in stock”
“quantity”: “100000”
}
```

> To set up a single rich product pin, use these required fields (color coded to match formula):
>   url: The canonical URL for the product.
>
> title: The product name. No need to use HTML formatting here since any tags will be removed.
>   price: The price of the product without any currency symbols.
>   currency_code: Easily find the correct currency code from xe.com. For example, the US dollar is listed as “USD”.

See also: http://oembed.com/ and [Pinterest richpins examples](https://dev.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/)

Comment: The only important thing missing here is the oembed api url or a link to some info on it. I can't find it anywhere.